# Find distance between two consecutive bounding boxes?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OCR to get the bounding of words.

How can i combine two consecutive bounding boxes that are quite closer to each other?

I am actually trying to get all the words present in specific cell of the table.
 For example, in the image given below, "Account" and "Number" are two separate words. I want to combine these bounding boxes based on the distance between those bounding boxes.
[image]

Comment: You need to come up with something. Nobody will write your code for you here.

Comment: note that the `59198482` is much closer to `ACCOUNT` than the `NUMBER`. Not saying that it is impossible, but I think it is a bit more complicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a union function to take two bounding boxes and return the bounding box which encloses both. That's trivial, just max / min.

Then check the area of the union against the area of the two components. If the difference is negative, the boxes are contained one in each other, if it is zero they are flush with each other. If the difference is small, the components are quite close. If it is large, the components are far apart or one is much bigger than the other in the common edge dimension, so you probably want to reject that union.